# Combine multiple videos as separate streams in one mkv file

Tags: video, editing, ffmpeg

So I have multiple videos of the same scenery from different angles. These are stored as separate files. Can I combine these as multiple video streams within one file?

For example I know this is possible with MKV, I just don't know how to "join" them.

Is this possible using *ffmpeg*? If so, which command sequence do I use?
If not, what other application would be able to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using ffmpeg and the `mkv` container.

An example command sequence would be:

```
ffmpeg -i input1 -i input2 -c copy -map 0 -map 1 output.mkv
```

<sub>[source](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=828)</sub>

Breaking down the command:

- `-i input1` This selects the first input file. Could be something like my `video_track1.mov`.
- `-i input2` Here you can specify the second input file. You can add another entry `-i input3` if you have more input videos. I don't know what the maximum amount of videos is you can place in one `mkv` container.
- `-c copy` This copies all the streams (audio and video) in their original encoding.
- `-map 0` This maps all the streams (audio and video) of the first input file to the first track of the output file.
- `-map 1` This maps all the streams (audio and video) of the second input file to the second track of the output file.

More information on the `-map` option can be found [in the documentation of ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options).

Comment: Thank you Bart. Just a quick follow-up question if I may. Suppose the 2nd video is a bit shorter than the 1st video I want to combine, is there any way I can offset at which point the second stream should be available (eg. 1 second later), to keep the two streams in sync?

Comment: Not sure, I'm not an expert, just a happy Googler, but you could experiment with the [`-ss` option](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking%20with%20FFmpeg#Cuttingsmallsections). Please edit your question with the addition and add an answer yourself including the ffmpeg code if you find that it works. This will help future visitors.

Comment: This almost worked, but my input video didnt have timestamps. I created them with `ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i input1_no_ts.avi -c copy input1.mp4` and `ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i input2_no_ts.avi -c copy input2.mp4`

Answer (score -1):

'map' selects input sources, files in this case. Your command combines all the tracks into a single stream, not separate ones as desired.

Comment: The command in @SaaruLindestakke answer keeps them as separate streams. `map` does not combine streams; it can only select input **streams** (not files).